# Getting a slug to save in vue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using both vue and laravel and I'm trying to create a product form that creates a slug as you type. I've managed to get
the slug to show up as you type but I'm not sure as to how I should save it to my database.

My vue

```
<template>
    <div class="product-form">
        <form v-on:submit="onSubmit(model)">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" name="title" v-model="model.title">
                <input type="hidden" name="slug" title="slug" :value="slug(model.title)">
                <p>{{ slug(model.title) }}</p>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Save"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                model: {
                    title: '',
                    slug: '',
                },

            };
        },

        methods: {
             slug() {
                var title = this.model.title;

                var slug_test = title.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
                return slug_test;
            },

            onSubmit: function(model){

                event.preventDefault();

                this.$http.post('/database/articles', model)
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How does your post route and controller look like? And any errors?

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to keep the `slug` property of your model up to date with the `title` property.
The cleanest approach here would be a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on your `title` that updates the `slug`, or by computing `model.slug` right before you POST it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can append slug in Model Resource if you are using Laravel